# Create personal page for every user, PHP

Tags: php, account

What I want to do is to create a web page for every user when they signup on my page.

For Example: **www.someweb.com/username**, and this will be their webpage.

I know that this can be done easily with `mkdir()` and other related functions, but the problem is that my root folder is not `chmod 777` and I don't want to `chmod 777` this root folder because of security reasons.

What is the best way to do this when a user registers on my web page.

Comment: Can some one let me know how to configure the RewriteRule for this yrl: http://www.someweb.com/users.php?username=agonfx21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't make physical directories for each user, you use URL rewriting. Take a look at this source:

[HTML Source : HTML Tutorials, *URL Rewriting*](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html)

Answer (score 7):

Most likely you don't need to create these directories in real.
Just make it virtual.
Pass a username using query string, like this:

```
www.someweb.com/index.php?user=username
```

And personalize this page according to particular username.
After that you can do some rewrite magic and make a page address like this `www.someweb.com/username` but all pages will remain virtual

Comment: The problem is that i want this to be as i pointed up there, is more professional and much clean

Comment: Dear @AXheladini before making it look professional, you have to make it just work. An only then do some decorations, bells and whistles.

Answer (score 6):

Use `mod_rewrite` to make a request to `/username` actually be `?user=username`. You can then get the appropriate user's data and display it in a template.

Comment: how to configure the RewriteRule for this yrl: someweb.com/users.php?username=agonfx21

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create personal page for each user after signup

->when a new user do the signup at ur site then create a new directory with the name of username at the location of user folder like 
      /user/username/

create a file under this directory with name of index by using create file function
     /user/username/index
write the following code using read/write operations if ur using php

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("\user\$_SESSION["username"].php", "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
$str = "<?php 
        \$p_username = ".$_SESSION['username']."; 
        include('../user-profile.php');
    ?>";
fwrite($myfile, $str);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

this user-profile will have the functionality to retrieve the user info from the database with the help of variable $p_username. in this way an user can also visit the profile of other user